# Calabash-Android on Windows

Tags: android, windows, cucumber, calabash, gherkin

I am not sure if this is topic is already discussed recently, but I´m getting really frustrated searching the web on my own, trying several guides and fixes. I´ve done so much stuff I cannot really tell what I already did :(

So I´m trying to run Calabash-Android on Windows 10 64bit, I followed the steps on https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android, I installed ruby, Ant and the DevKit. When I now try to run a test with:

```
calabash-android run app-release.apk
```

I get an output like this:

```
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
WARNING: cannot load such file -- gherkin_lexer_en
Couldn't load gherkin_lexer_en
The $LOAD_PATH was:
lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/bin/../lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/builder-3.2.2/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/diff-lcs-1.2.5/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.2/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/multi_test-0.1.2/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/slowhandcuke-0.0.3/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/awesome_print-1.6.1/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.0.1/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/escape-0.0.4/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/i386-msvcrt
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/i386-msvcrt
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32. Reverting to Ruby lexer.
No lexer was found for en (cannot load such file -- gherkin/lexer/en). Supported languages are listed in gherkin/i18n.json. (Gherkin::I18n::LexerNotFound)
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:108:in `rescue in lexer'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/i18n.rb:97:in `lexer'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:139:in `transition_table'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:128:in `build_transition_map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:124:in `transition_map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:91:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:68:in `new'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:68:in `push_machine'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib/gherkin/parser/parser.rb:31:in `parse'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:37:in `parse'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:28:in `block in load'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `load'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:14:in `features'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:179:in `features'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:49:in `run!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby21/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

So I googled this first error "Warning cannot load such file[...], found multiple results, tried this https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/issues/320, tried:

```
gem install gherkin --platform=ruby
```

got an output like this:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gherkin:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby
        --with-gherkin_lexer_ar-dir
        --without-gherkin_lexer_ar-dir
        --with-gherkin_lexer_ar-include
        --without-gherkin_lexer_ar-include=${gherkin_lexer_ar-dir}/include
        --with-gherkin_lexer_ar-lib
        --without-gherkin_lexer_ar-lib=${gherkin_lexer_ar-dir}/lib
        --with-clib
        --without-clib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:736:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:967:in `block in have_library'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:912:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:962:in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/gherkin-2.12.2/gem_make.out
```

I´m quite sure I did several fixes, but nothing worked for me, maybe you guys can help me? Really need to make this work. Maybe I just missed some little detail?

Greets
Kapasko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody wondering, I fixed this issue by removing all components and installing them again. I can not explain why it now works, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on an experimental Calabash Sandbox for Windows that may help.

In an Admin Powershell, run:

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
```

then

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/calabash/install/master/install-windows.ps1") | powershell -command -
```

then open a command prompt (not a powershell) and run

```
calabash-sandbox
```

Inside of that sandbox, all of the calabash-android commands should work, and you'll have a preconfigured ruby environment (it doesn't affect the rest of your system's ruby configuration).

To exit the sandbox, just type `exit`

When you're all finished with installation, remember to run this in a powershell:

```
set-executionpolicy restricted
```

Just to be safe :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and I believe it was due to mismatching dependencies. When I tried installing the required gems using Bundler, the issue was resolved.

Bundler can help you manage all dependencies very easy by using a gemfile.

Try this ==> bundler.io/#getting-started